# Django + Postgres __in optimization

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a few queries that are taking up the majority of my DB access time in production, and I want to optimize them.  This is complicated because the slow execution shows up in production, but not in my smaller local data set.  Based on some reading, I have come to believe the problem is the `__in` clause.

These problem sections follow the same general pattern: slice out some related objects, then run a big `__in` query to get my working objects for later analysis.  (Tellingly, they are the only sections with this pattern).  Based on what I read [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/ways-to-speed-up-in-queries-under-postgresql), the `__in` part of the query is an issue.  The answer says postgres runs a sequential scan for in lookups, and that can be sped up with joins.  This explains the divergence in production, but writing raw SQL as a solution seems like a red flag for what should be a common use case.

Some example models:

```
class Book(models.Model):

    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        (RED, 'Red'),
        (BLUE, 'Blue'),
        (GREEN, 'Green'),
    )
    color = models.IntegerField(
        choices=COLOR_CHOICES,
        default=RED
    )
    published = models.DateField()
    author = models.CharField()

class Page(models.Model):

    book = models.ForeignKey('Book')
    text = models.TextField()
    page_number = models.IntegerField()
```

If I want the first page of the most recent 100 books by color, I do something like

```
#Get first pages of 100 most recently published books by color
reds = Book.objects.filter(color=Book.RED).order_by('-published')[:100]
greens = Book.objects.filter(color=Book.GREEN).order_by('-published')[:100]
blues = Book.objects.filter(color=Book.BLUE).order_by('-published')[:100]

books = list(itertools.chain(reds, greens, blues))

pages = Page.objects.filter(page_number=1, book__in(books))
```

and the relevant part of the query comes out as

```
 WHERE "page"."book_id" IN (%s, %s, ...)
```

rather than an optimized join.  Is the linked answer correct that in () query clauses can be improved upon, and what is the Django-official route to do this?

Comment: Try to dig up the generated query (from the postgres logfile) and the definition of the table(s) (is page.book_id a primary key, or at least indexed?)

Comment: It should be the primary key ID field that django automatically adds to objects.

Comment: BTW: how long is the `IN ( ... , ... , )` list ?

Comment: Looks ugly -> Try to obtain a query plan.  ( + timing :: `explain analyze`, or pull it from the logs)

Comment: I know this is a very old case.... but have you ever figured out this one?